# How to catch reliably and battery-friendly "leave house" events within 50m in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, location, core-location

I want to catch reliably and battery-friendly "leave house" events before the user walks more than 50m away from the house.

Is that even possible?

Comment: Ofc it's possible, but keep in mind that best accuracy will cause battery drain, if you simply want to send notification, use UNNotification with location based trigger, then system will handle it, else use CoreLocation tracking with background enable.

Comment: It probably isn't possible with those exact specifications.  You can use significant location change or a geofence, but you can't guarantee notification within 50m; a geofence will be better than significant location change however.  High precision location tracking will give you 50m resolution easily but isn't battery friendly.